# How to work with git

Tags: git, branch

We want to start using git, but there are some question about branches.

How it is organized:

1. Each programmer has his own local repository and works in master branch.
2. Any changes are pushed to bare repository.
3. Development server has local repository (master branch) and is updated by Post-Push hook
4. Production server has local repository (branch "production") and is updated by Post-Push hook

How to correctly push some commits from master to production?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question, your bare repo has hook that will push to production server when commits arrive in `production` branch, in the same way your dev server is updated. What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: How to push commits from master branch to production? For example: i make some commits to master, someone has tested this commit and i must push it to production.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, you need to merge the changes from master into production. So in some workspace, switch to the production branch, merge the master branch and then push to the dev and production servers. This can be done in any developer's workspace.

Provided no changes are made to the production branch directly, all the merges will be "fast-forwards"- i.e. the "production branch" will basically just be a pointer to a position on your master branch, indicating at which point production was last updated. This means that merging will never produce any conflicts either. Technically you *could* do a "git push origin master:production" to update the production branch on the remote server in this case.

Comment: But i need to merge not the whole master branch, only some commits

Comment: I need something like this: select commit on dev server and push it to production.

Comment: in that case, check out the production branch and use the "cherry-pick" command to apply the commit onto master. and imho forget about ever merging the branches.

Comment: It is possible to do it backwards? So no one will touch production?

Comment: well, someone needs to touch production to push the update. and if you're cherry-picking like this, you need to account for the possibility that the changes you're pulling into production will need merging, if they're entagled with a previous change that wasn't picked.

Answer (score 1):

Having an intermediate repo (here "Development") is a good practice in order to consolidate and debug commits which are candidate to be put in production.

But I would rather create a release branch (for instance '`rel2.3`') on the intermediate repo in order to be able to make last fixes/minor adjustment, before pushing '`rel2.3`' to '`production`' branch of the prod repo (along with a tag, in order to mark the exact commit representing 2.3)

So an individual dev shouldn't push into productiob directly: only the 'integrator' (or tester) who has validated what has been push on the intermediate repo should push to prod.

And I would create an '`rel2.3_hotfixes`' branch on the prod repo in order to isolate urgent fixes once into production.

So that would means each repo (devs, and 'Development') need to be in sync (ie rebased on) the production branch, which could have added commits after a given release.

Comment: In our product it is hard to implement release versions.

Comment: @DigitalGod that means: sequential development only, you don't need to isolate any fix in their own branch. That sounds simpler than my model then.